# Authenticate with Podio API using google signin

Tags: podio

I am a newbie on Podio API and most of my users in my company is logging in Podio using their Google account instead of creating a separate Podio account. However, I don't found any documentation on Podio regarding authenticating users using Google OAuth2. Any clues or ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To use Google authentication you should follow https://developers.podio.com/authentication/client_side authentication flow.

First time user logins with Google credentials and then your app can save access_token/refresh_token and use them when needed.

Comment: Can I use app auth in my client application (mobile app)? As I understand, the token will expired soon that each of the client will need to retrieve a new token everytime? Is that all the old token will be expired when I retrieve a new one?

Comment: You can not combine google signin and app auth :( 
In any way there will be access_token and refresh_token. Access_token will eventually expire, it has 'expires_in' property. Refresh token will never expire and is used to get new access token. Even more details on how it all works are right here: https://developers.podio.com/authentication

Comment: can i just use app auth? is that i still need each of my client app to refresh everytime? will it cause a crashing issue, i.e. user A and user B are both using the app to create a form, which caused a racing condition as they both try to get a new token?

Comment: User A and user B might both use app auth, and they should not conflict.

Comment: As mentioned in Podio doc, each time i auth with App Auth, the token can only allow me to do changes on single Podio app only? and each of my client app will need to call podio to do app auth everytime before they fire API call to podio?

Comment: Each time you auth as app - you get access only yo that app. 
Each api call have to be authenticated, but you don't have to call auth before every API call, just use same auth token until it's expired (and then refresh auth token)